# Отправка почты с помощью PowerShell. Вопрос авторизации

Tags: powershell, exchange

Добрый день.

Имеется Exchange 2013, терминальный сервер с пользователями и необходимость отправлять с терминала почту на внешние адреса используя PS скрипт.
При этом крайне неохота заставлять Exchange пересылать сообщения с терминала только с IP авторизацией.

Скажите, как авторизироваться на exchange сервере с учетными данными, с которыми пользователь зашел на терминальный сервер?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы кусок скрипта, который отправляет почту. Пока непонятно, как вы это делаете, и в чём конкретно проблема.

Comment: Пытался делать с помощью Send-MailMessage и Smtp.Send, но автоматически авторизация не проходит

Answer (score 1):

send-mailmessage -to "to@todomain.ru" -from "from@fromdomain.ru" -subj
ect "Test mail" -SMTPServer nameserver

Также в этом же командлете можно указать креденшиалы, если машины в домене, то будет использована NTLM-аутентификация и это не понадобится. Если не в домене - проверьте

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все в домене, у учетки есть ящик, с него пытаюсь отправлять. Но в описанном вами случае авторизация не проходит и получаю "5.7.1 Unable to relay".

Comment: попробуйте -Credential (get-credential) добавить к команде и ввести свои учетные данные в том виде как авторизуетесь на cas-е
SMTPServer - адрес cas сервера, не edge

Comment: `5.7.1 Unable to relay` - ну так, может, нужно проверить настройки, кому разрешен relay?

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка может возникать если отправка производится от имени сервера. Попробуйте дать серверу право отправки от имени пользователя, а в свойствах учётной записи сервера заполнить UserPrincipalName вида <имя сервера>@<имя домена>.